# MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a small little app but I'm getting the error "...MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup" and no display is setting up. I'm trying to have a button that switches states and text when it's selected. Any help would be much appreciated.

Main class:

```
package rechee.pro.sound;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class PrometheusSoundActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ImageButton pressed;
    ImageButton not_pressed;

    private MediaPlayer mp;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

         ImageButton pressed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pressed);
        pressed.setOnClickListener(this);

         ImageButton not_pressed= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.not_pressed);
        not_pressed.setOnClickListener(this);

       // View clickButton= findViewById(R.id.click_button);
       //clickButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    int resId;
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(pressed.isSelected()){
            resId= R.raw.sound;
            mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
            mp.start();



        }
        if(not_pressed.isSelected()){
            mp.stop();
        }

        if(mp!=null){
            mp.release();
        }



    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/promethus">
        <item android:id="@+id/not_pressed"
            android:state_pressed="false"
            android:text="@string/Click"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/pressed"
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:text="@string/stop_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </selector>




</LinearLayout>
```

Strings xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="hello">Hello World, PrometheusSoundActivity!</string>
    <string name="Click">Click here</string><string name="stop_button">Stop</string><string name="app_name">Prometheus Sound</string>



</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can put a selector inside a linear layout like that, or if android:id is even a valid tag to have inside a selector item (see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). If you want to have a button that changes states when it's pressed, ToggleButton lends itself to what you want to do (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) or you can programatically set the button to change it's text when it's pressed. In the case when you use a toggle button, you'd declare it in your xml as ToggleButton.

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOff="textThatShowsWhenButtonIsOff"
    android:textOn="textThatShowsWhenButtonIsPressed" />
```

and:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton) arg0;
    if (button.isChecked()) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Button is now checked");
    } else {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Button is now off");
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're able to have text for a togglebutton? There's no text that appears.

Comment: Yeah - the text should show. That's what the textOff and textOn attributes are for. If you can't see the text check your text color and background, or just post all your source and I'll try to help you out. I just wrote a sample button out with the code and it works fine for me.

Comment: I'm getting a unhandled loop error. I'll update what happens when I fix that problem.

Comment: I'm getting this weird bug. When I try to click on one of my xml attributes, the text will move randomly and some of my text will be deleted. Weird. I'm done for now. I'll work on the problem more tomorrow.